# How to view all changes delivered to a stream in RTC source control

Tags: clearcase, rtc

How can I view all changes delivered to a stream and/or changes delivered by a specific developer ?
I could see the activities listed for a given ClearCase UCM stream, but I don't see anything with an RTC Stream.

I've been considering using a 'Work Item Query' but this does not seem to allow this functionality ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search for change sets (a bit like you would list ClearCase activities sorted by owner):

Right-click on "`Source-Control`" and select "`Search / Change sets`": you will be able to make your query there.

[image: Search for Change sets]

Another less know place o see those change sets is in the "Team Dashboard" view, section "Events log", which you can filter by "Source control changes".

---

You will find more illustrations on "Change set searching" in:

- The [RTC feature page](https://jazz.net/products/rational-team-concert/features/scm/) and this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyX32R7da2c&feature=player_embedded).
- The article "[Finding Lost Content with Rational Team Concert](https://jazz.net/library/article/191/)" proposes some alternatives to change set searches.
- [This thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/35697/how-to-search-for-files-in-a-stream-without-loading-it), which confirms "You can search for files with a given name, but you cannot currently search for files containing given text."

The result doesn't seem to display files directly through: using the field "Name begins with" is a way to limit the number of files included in those change sets.

And [other](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=201476) [enhancements](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=152775) [are](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=172480) [in progress](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=154308) for that feature: see [this search](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.search&q=search%20files%20change%20sets).

Comment: thanks, this does'nt seem to list the filenames of the changes made ? Also I can just search at a component level, not at a stream level ?

Comment: @user470184 component level: yes, just enter the component. It will give you a list of changeset (which contains files), not directly the list of files.

Comment: sorry I mean to ask : can I just search at a stream level instead of a component level

Comment: @user470184 yes: put `<any component>` in the `Component` field, and a Stream name in the `Location` field.

Comment: yep, also seems to work if put in any repository workspace which flows to the stream. I can view the changed files by opening the individual search result element. I don't think there is an easier method ?

Comment: @user470184 sorry for the delay. I have completed the answer. It is true the result is first based on change sets. You might limit the number of files returns with the field "Name begins with" though.